# Cannot get insertion sort in python code below to work

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, error-handling, insertion

I have the following code that seeks to perform an insertion sort on the array 'numbers'. (and print the sorted array)

There appears to be a logic error in the algorithm, but I cannot spot it as it seems to make sense.

Can anyone suggest a solution using the existing code with a suitable explanation?

```
numbers=[4,1,2,5,3]
for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    position=1
    while position>0 and numbers[position]<numbers[position-1]:
      #print("Position:",numbers[position])
      #print("Position-1:",numbers[position-1])
      temp=numbers[position-1]
      numbers[position-1]=numbers[position]
      numbers[position]=temp
      #print("New value of position",numbers[position])

      position=position+1
print(numbers)

print("Insertion Sort)
```

Comment: Please provide what is the actual result and what is the expected result, and also what you have already tried to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple modification to your program your insertion sort will work.

`while position>0` will always be true because position is incremented.

```
numbers=[4,1,2,5,3]
last_num = len(numbers)-1
for i in range(last_num):
    position=i
    while position<last_num:
        if numbers[position]>numbers[position+1]:
            temp=numbers[position+1]
            numbers[position+1]=numbers[position]
            numbers[position]=temp
        position+=1

print(numbers)

print("Insertion Sort")
```

prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Insertion Sort
```

Edit:
with `position>0` you need

```
numbers=[4,1,2,5,3]
last_num = len(numbers)-1
for i in range(last_num):
    position=last_num
    while position>0:
        if numbers[position]<numbers[position-1]:
            temp=numbers[position-1]
            numbers[position-1]=numbers[position]
            numbers[position]=temp
        position-=1

print(numbers)

print("Insertion Sort")
```

Comment: Is there no way in which it could be done with the while position > 0 using the current algorithm?